# How can I transfer data via bluetooth from an iOS device to a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, bluetooth

I want to be able to transfer basic information (strings and such) from an iOS device to a Mac, and vice versa, via apps installed on each device. I've been trying to get bluetooth on the iOS device, but it seems to only want to connect to other iOS devices.

Comment: i had seen a app that transferred data between Mac and iPhone through bonjour networking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth access on the ios is very limited. As a matter of fact you can only access it through the GameKit.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

So if you want to share information with a Mac you would have to make the mac appear as an iOS device. I however ignore how you could do this.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I've found tutorials and stuff using the GameKit, but that's only iOS to iOS

Comment: Because there is no official access to the bluetooth appart from this library. So if you want your app to be accepted you would have to use this library and focus on emulating an iOS device on your mac application.